# How to update mongodb with realtime data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am to update my mongodb collection with live currency data at the same time i will query my database using node api to get the currency data from my mobile app.I have planned to run a scheduler every 10 minutes so that my database will be updated with real time currency rates.My question here is will my mobile app be affected if two operations happen at the same time ie : scheduler runs to get the live data at the same time user's querying data from the mobile app ? How to handle this situation ?

P.s : I will be using react native for the mobile development and node + mongodb for the server

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

"How to handle this situation" is totally based on your application needs, there are lots of configurable parts to mongodb, to start with you should read up on write and read concerns:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

> Write concern describes the level of acknowledgement requested from MongoDB for write operations to a standalone mongod or to replica sets or to sharded clusters.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/

> The readConcern query option for replica sets and replica set shards determines which data to return from a query.

In the default situation, your writes will be atomic per document, which depending on how you've modeled your documents maybe ok? You'll also have a default read concern of local meaning that it will read from the current primary even if the write has not propagated to the secondaries. and then a write concern to acknowledge that the write has been written to the primary.